# NetLogo "go" procedure cannot proceed forever

Tags: netlogo

I built a NetLogo model to simulate the crowd evacuation. The "go" procedure is needed to run forever until the stop condition is met.

Here is the strange thing: sometimes the "go" button works properly, but sometimes the "go" stops after only one run (I do check the "forever" box), and I have to click the "go" button manually and continuously to proceed the model, and no warnings or errors were thrown out, but the tick remains 0, and the print commands in "go" procedure cannot print anything in the output window. And the weird thing is sometimes when I wait for a while and open the model again, it is normal.

I doubt this might relate with the memory issue because the model usually works fine when I reduce the number of agents. But if it is, should it throw out the "out of memory" error?

Could someone give some suggestions about my problem?

Comment: can we see the code for the go procedure at least, and the stop condition?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code for go procedure is quite a lot since it is a complex model, I am trying to reduce the code to identify the problem, and I will post the code later.

Comment: +1 for "reduc[ing] the code to identify the problem". There is a good chance that this process will help you figure out what is going on...

Comment: As you reduce your `go` code, you might want to set up separate procedures for sections. Typically, a NetLogo `go` procedure is simply a series of calls to other procedures. This makes the logic clearer and helps with debugging as it is easier to test parts of the code. Have a look at the Models Library for some examples of this modular approach.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I found the problem by reconstructing the code, it is just due to a mistake I made, not related with NetLogo itself. Thank you again :)